# Change the default for Activity related to

Tags: configuration, activities, language

I'm using Salesforce in two languages - English and Spanish. When I create a new event in activity, there is an option to choose which object it is related to.

[image]

In the English org, by default, the related to object is accounts. However, when I switch the language to Spanish, the default related to object is Activos, ie., Asset.

[image]

Currently, the default related to object is the first object in the dropdown picklist.

I would like the default related to object in the Spanish org to also be Accounts(Cuentas in Spanish). Right now, I need to choose Cuentas in the dropdown to use it as the related to object. Is there any way to change the default related to object in activity to Cuentas when using the org in Spanish?